# Select control stops showing its drop down list with IE, AngularJS and some strangely-specific conditions

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I have a weird problem whereby a `<select>` control stops showing its drop down list in IE11 using AngularJS after changing the value (twice).

Chrome (42) and FF (37) do not exhibit the issue.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ea0nMnPxXdqm8O59NyZS?p=preview

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xydvqo0q/

Steps:

1. Click the select to open its drop down list.
2. Select either of the two listed options. (It closes and a couple of other fields in the page update their values.)
3. Click to open again.
4. Select the other option. (It closes and the fields update again.)
5. Click to open the drop down list again. **Will no longer open**

Neither mouse click, nor Alt-downarrow will show the drop down once it gets into this state.

(Further, other selects on the same page also stop showing their drop down lists, and there appears to be a general control/windowing issue for the page - e.g. you can't select HTML text, and other controls won't show the focus or caret. Seems like IE loses the plot about which is the active "window" and it seems to be stuck inside the select. Pressing Tab a few times gets it out of this stuck state.)

Now, an IE control/windowing bug isn't unusual. But this is weird because of the specific set of requirements to reproduce. I've stripped back the example to what seems to be the minimum required to reproduce (yet you might think there's heaps of stuff in the page that should be irrelevant - afraid not).

The page needs the following for the issue to show:

- The nested table (which lists "hello"s) must be there (and it must be nested - if it's not inside another table then the problem goes away). (I made it list hellos to eliminate it listing scope data to eliminate that as a cause.)
- The table row which contains `{{selecteditem.number}}` must be there, and must be AFTER the nested table (moving it before removes the issue). I moved it to a separate table and the problem remains.
- The `selecteditem.number` data must be different for the two items. If the "number" values are the same for the two items, it will not show the issue.
- The number of "sub items" for each of the two items must be the SAME (meaning the nested table ends up with the same number of rows). If you add another sub-item to one of the items, the problem is fixed. If you add a sub-item to both (so they both have two) then the problem returns.
- (Are you thinking I'm crazy yet? I thought I was. But wait there's more...)
- The nested table must have the CSS property `border-collapse: collapse`. Without this property, or with a different value for this property, the issue doesn't occur. Note: the table can inherit this property from the parent table, or from a table CSS rule, or from a class (as the demo shows) and the issue still occurs. Removing it "live" using IE's F12 dev console and the issue gets fixed.
- The `TD`s of the nested table - i.e. the "hellos" - must have a CSS border. They can inherit this, or obtain it from the class (as per the demo).

Basically, I have to tell the client they can have a collapsed-bordered table to show sub-items in the table of fields (there are usually many more than in the demo) or have a drop down list, but not both. (Or don't use IE, which isn't an option, or change the order of you form, which then would make no sense to the users.)

I tried not using `ng-options` (and instead `ng-repeat`-ing an `option`) but I get the same result (I'm limited to 2 links so here's the plnkr ID: 95XcM9j2eY70jUK10UrH).

I may dump the select entirely.